# Prove that $\sqrt{\frac{a}{b+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{a+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{a+b}} \gt 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

Prove that If $a,b,c \in R^+$ Then

$$\sqrt{\frac{a}{b+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{a+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{a+b}} \gt 2$$

My try:

I assumed:

$$x=\sqrt{\frac{a}{b+c}}$$

$$y=\sqrt{\frac{b}{a+c}}$$

$$x=\sqrt{\frac{c}{b+a}}$$

Then we have:

$$\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}=\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\right)+\left(\frac{a}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\right)+\left(\frac{c}{b}+\frac{b}{c}\right)$$

Now by AM GM Inequality we have:

$$\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\right) \ge 2$$

So we get:

$$\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2} \ge 6 \tag{1}$$

Using $(1)$ we need to prove:

$$x+y+z \gt 2$$

Any idea here?

Comment: (1) does not give you $x+y+z >2$.

Comment: but how can $c=0$, $a,b,c$ are positive reals

Comment: @Umeshshankar Right, you should probably mention that $a, b, c > 0$, because $\mathbb{R}^+$ is a bit ambiguous whether it includes $0$.

Answer (score 4):

Writing cyclic sums for short,
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a}{b+c}}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{2a}{2\sqrt{a(b+c)}}\\
\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{2a}{a+b+c}=2
$$
where the AM-GM inequality was used for each denominator, i.e. $2\sqrt{a(b+c)} \le a + (b+c)$

---

As Martin R. pointed out, math.stackexchange.com/a/2237066/42969 has the same reasoning, so credits belong to Michael Rozenberg. Here, some extra explanation is given.

Comment: So is the inequality $\ge 2$?

Comment: Yes. To be more precise, equality would only hold in the AM-GM terms if $a = b+c$, $b = a+c$, $c = b+a$ which would entail $a=b=c=0$ which is not possible. So we can exclude this case, and $>$  holds.

Comment: So you mean to say when AM GM is used there are some exceptions like this problems, where equality cannot occur.

Comment: Well, what do you mean by "exceptions"? I was explaning that equality in  AM-GM - as used here - holds if and only if the two terms are equal (in all three cases where AM-GM was used). Then I argued that if $a,b,c \in R^+$, this equality condition cannot occur. So I concluded that indeed $>$ holds.

Comment: Did you notice that I already pointed out a possible duplicate target? Your solution was already presented in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2237066/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Martin, thanks for driving my attention to it, indeed I hadn't noticed your comment. I looked at the source you gave: yes it has the same reasoning with a little less explanation. I put this in the text.  What are the rules: should I remove my answer?

Comment: @Andreas I am actually not clear. I just wanted to know for which values of $a,b,c$ we get $f(a,b,c)=2$. According to answer given by Rozenberg in linked post when $a=b=1$ and $c \to 0$ we get $f(a,b,c)\to 2$.Can you please clarify on this?

Comment: Yes, when any two variables are equal (not necessarily 1, just equal) and the third variable $\to 0$, $f\to 2$. Again, $f=2$ occurs if the third variable *equals* 0 which is ruled out by the condition $a,b,c \in R^+$.

Comment: But what i did is: i solved for $c$ when $f(a,b,c)=2$ and $a=b=1$, that is: $$\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{2}}=2$$, then real values i am getting are $c=0$ or $c=12.87$. So how come we say $c \to 0$

Comment: $c = 12.87$ does not give the solution 2.

Comment: Yes so can we say that $f(a,b,c)$ has no minimum ,but infimum is $2$

Comment: Yes that's how I would put it.