# Prove that for positive numbers x and y the inequality is true.

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Prove that for positive numbers x and y the inequality $$ \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{x+y}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{1+y}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{y}{1+x}}>2$$ is true.

I tried to use the inequality $$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{ab}} \geq \dfrac{2}{a+b}.$$

For example, the first fraction turns to
$$\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{(x+y)1}} \geq \dfrac{2}{x+y+1}.$$

The second fraction turns to $$\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{(1+y)1}} \geq \dfrac{2x}{y+2}.$$

The third fraction turns to $$\sqrt{\dfrac{y}{(1+x)1}} \geq \dfrac{2y}{x+2}.$$

So we have $$ \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{x+y}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{1+y}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{y}{1+x}} \geq \dfrac{2}{x+y+1}+\dfrac{2x}{2+y}+\dfrac{2y}{2+x} = 2 \left( \dfrac{1}{x+y+1}+\dfrac{x}{2+y}+\dfrac{y}{2+x}\right)>2.$$ Is it enough to prove that multiplying by 2, we get an expression greater than two?

Any hint would help a lot, Thanks!

Comment: Can you show how you applied the inequality for each of the 3 terms?

Comment: $\frac{2}{\frac{1}{x} + y + 1} ≠ \frac{2x}{2+y}$

Comment: @CalvinLin yes, I added this part, you can see it now

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: Why did you reopen the question? It looks like an exact duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1003117/42969 to me (and at least one of your solutions posted here is quite similar to what you answered to the older question).

Comment: @Martin R Your inequality has three variables, but the starting problem has two variables.  They are really different problems. Maybe you found out that they are both inequalities? It's not enough for me.

Comment: So this is a special case of the other problem, and even you treat it as $\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{x}{y+z}}$ in your answer below, and the solutions are identical.

Comment: @Martin R Yes, of course, I used math. It does not say that we need to delete any problems, where we use math. Don't agree.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Who said anything about *deleting* anything?  Closing a question as a duplicate *protects* it from the kind of automatic deletion that occurs with other close reasons, and helps future users to see related content.  I agree with Martin R that this *is* a duplicate question, and that it *should* be closed with a link to the duplicate.

Comment: @Xander Henderson♦ I don't agree with you. It's not duplicate. Also, you deleted very many "duplicates" like this. In my opinion it's very bad.

Comment: @AliceMalinova To clarify, can you show the second term too? I only got $2\sqrt{x}  / (2+y)$, or $ 2x/(xy+x+1)$ like An_Elephant.

Comment: @CalvinLin I added, see it now.

Comment: Can you write it out step by step? Please humor me and show all of the working. $\quad$ FWIW I still only get $ 2 \sqrt{x} / (2+y)$ using what I think is your approach

Answer (score 1):

Let $1=z$.

Thus, by Holder and Schur we obtain: $$LHS=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{x}{y+z}}=\sqrt{\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{x}{y+z}}\right)^2\sum\limits_{cyc}x^2(y+z)}{\sum\limits_{cyc}x^2(y+z)}}\geq\sqrt{\frac{(x+y+z)^3}{\sum\limits_{cyc}x^2(y+z)}}>2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way.
By AM-GM $$\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{x+y}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{1+y}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{y}{1+x}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1(x+y)}}+\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x(1+y)}}+\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{y(1+x)}}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{2}{1+x+y}+\frac{2x}{x+1+y}+\frac{2y}{y+1+x}=2.$$
The equality occurs for $1=x+y$, $x=1+y$ and $y=1+x,$ which says that the equality does not occur.